# MYSQL How to join column in query result?

Tags: mysql

I have this MYSQL query

```
SELECT username,password,enabled FROM USERS WHERE username=?
```

that outputs 3 columns: username, password, enabled.

Now what I want to do is include email_address in the query and **OUTPUT IT ALSO UNDER USERNAME** column

```
SELECT username,password,enabled FROM USERS WHERE username=? or email_address=?
```

and still outputs 3 columns: username(could be from email_address), password, enabled.

*Can I do that? How?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using COALESCE you should get the first available result only. So if there is data in the username than that will show in the column, otherwise the email_address will show.

```
SELECT COALESCE(username, email_address),password,enabled FROM USERS WHERE username=? or email_address=?
```

CONCAT_WS will get the data from both columns and put it into one

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', username, email_address),password,enabled FROM USERS WHERE username=? or email_address=?
```

Comment: I think coalesce is what I'm looking for. I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: Just a follow-up, how could I return the email address and not the username in:
"SELECT COALESCE(username, email_address),password,enabled FROM USERS WHERE username=? or email_address=?"
if (username=?) returns false??

username column is always returning usernames and not email_addresses

Comment: `COALESCE(email_address, username)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT('"', username, '" <', email_address, '>') as username
FROM users
WHERE ...
```